# resource(29, mysql link persistent)

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

When i use the var_dump($row); on my code a line appiers on te web page saying resource(29, mysql link persistent) what dose this mean ? im new to php and codeignite so make it simple if u can, thank you very much.

controller.php

```
<?php

class Survay extends CI_Controller{

function index()
{
          $data = array(
         'question' => $this->input->post('question'),
          'answer1' => $this->input->post('answer1'),
          'answer2' => $this->input->post('answer2'),
          'answer3' => $this->input->post('answer3'),
          'answer4' => $this->input->post('answer4'),
          'answer5' => $this->input->post('answer5'),
          'answer6' => $this->input->post('answer6'),
           );


           if($query = $this->membership_model->get_records()){
           $data['records'] = $query;
           }

           $this->page();

           $this->load->view('survay_view', $data);

           }

//pagination
        function page()
           {

            $this->load->library('pagination');


            $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/admin/index.php/survay/';
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('save_survay')->num_rows();

            $config['per_page'] = 1;
            $config['num_links'] =10;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            //print_r($this->uri->segment());die;

            $data['records'] = $this->db->get('save_survay', $config['per_page'], 
            $this->uri->segment(2,0));

            $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $this->load->view('survay_view', $data);

          }
    }

?>
```

view.php

```
     </head>
   <body>


            <h1>Answer</h1>
            <?php if (isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>

      <div = 'container'>




          <ul>
             <?php 
          if (isset($pagination))
            {
            echo $pagination;
            } 


           ?>
           <h1><?php  echo  $row->question; ?></h1>

           <li><?php  echo  $row->answer1; ?></li>
           <li><?php  echo  $row->answer2; ?></li>
             <li><?php  echo  $row->answer3; ?></li>
             <li><?php  echo  $row->answer4; ?></li>
             <li><?php  echo  $row->answer5; ?></li>
             <li><?php  echo  $row->answer6; ?></li>
          <ul>

       </div>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
          <?php else : ?>
          <h2>no records were returned</h2>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your code snippet?

Comment: i keep getting an error that says

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/survay_view.php

Line Number: 33

Comment: There are several problems with the above code. The first of which is that your database code `$this->db->get()` is in the controller. To comply with the MVC method of programming, this code should really be placed in a Model. It won't break your code, but it will help you separate your code and make it more manageable. The problem that is giving you the above error is that you need to use `$this->db->get()->result()` to return a results object.

Comment: I suggest reading the codeigniter documentation, specifically this page: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html 

The documentation is available in a range of languages, https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Language-Translation

Comment: can u expand more on these errors explonations? and how i can fix them i would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object Filename: views/survay_view.php Line Number: 33

The reason you receive the above error is because you are trying to access data held in the $records array as an object `$row->some_variable`, and it would appear that this data is not an object.

You are using the following code to get your results from the database:

`$data['records'] = $this->db->get('save_survay', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(2,0));`

The above code runs a query on the database, but this alone is not generating any results in a useful format. What it does return is an array consisiting of various pieces of data concerning the query, inside of which are the results.

To access the results as an object, you can adjust your code as follows:

`$data['records'] = $this->db->get('save_survay', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(2,0))->result();`

If you wanted the results returned as an array, you could use the following:

`$data['records'] = $this->db->get('save_survay', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(2,0))->result_array();`

As I mentioned above in the comments, I really recommend reading the documentation, especially the page about [Generating Query Results](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: thank you so much for ur help u saved me from a lot of headaches :) i am reading the document right now